# Running Hive on spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Trying to run hive on spark,using the below properties for the same. Tried tweaking some other properties as well like number of executor instances,spark master but throwing the error "FAILED: SemanticException Failed to get a spark session: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to create spark client."

Its running fine when spark.master is set to local.

The job is not getting instantiated. Any inputs?

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set spark.executor.memory=2g;
set yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=8192;
set yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=40960;
set spark.executor.cores=4;
set spark.executor.memory=4g;
set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=750;
set hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout=900000ms;
set yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=2048;
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, plus hive is ignoring my `spark.executor.memory` configuration, and when the application starts, it starts with 1024 mb executor memory and a `return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask`
The rest of the time I get the same `Failed to create spark client.` as you.

Comment: @alonsos which version of hive are you using,i have figured out that it would not work for hive version < 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Hive on spark will not work for Hive version < 2.1